# How files will be loaded in Visual Studio C++ when built

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have three files.

```
Wood.cpp
Brick.cpp
Wall.cpp
```

And my `main()` function is in Brick.cpp:

Now, when I run the project, it throws error that the `className` (which is in Wall.cpp) is undefined. What should I do?

I think the `main()` function is run before the delaration of Wall.cpp file.

Comment: do you have any .hpp in your project? please post at least the code with the problem and the exact error message

Comment: http://david.rothlis.net/c/compilation_model/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to tell the c++ compiler what function would be available and implemented, in C++ the way is using headers files:

Example:

File a.hpp

```
class A {
  // variable members
  // function signatures or inline functions
};
```

File a.cpp

```
// Implementation of functions in class A and initialization of static variables in A
```

File b.hpp

```
#include "a.hpp"

// Could use class A
class B {

   A m_a_member_variable;
}
```

File b.cpp

```
// Implementation of functions in class B and initialization of static variables in B that could use classes and declarations in a.hpp (ex: class A)
```

Answer (score 0):

`I think the main() function is run before the delaration of Wall.cpp file.` there is no **run before** while compiling. also, the compilation order is defined by the compiler.

you need to include the header (ussualy *.h, *.hpp, *.hh) file (if you have one, otherwise you have to create one) where `className` is defined into the source file where you use this class.

for the compiler it is enough to know the declaration (which is in the header) of a class to compile the source. the declaration is then necessary for the linker.

Comment: no I do not have any header file. My classes are declared in .cpp files.

Comment: then you have to create one. google first link on [c++ tutorial header](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/19-header-files/), or better [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/).